# Загрузить целую карту

Tags: unity3d

Возможно ли загрузить целую сцену в бандл и дальнейшее загрузка сцены и бандла?

Comment: Щепотку русского языка и пачку смысла, пожалуйста.   P.s. Краткость здесь не талант.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ возможно ли собрать карту в bundle и далее загрузить ее из bundle с последующей загрузкой как уровня

Comment: Да, возможно так

Comment: @Xumera_hZ можете поделиться примером?игровые объекты я определял по типу